# GUI Programming Language

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, programming-languages

Don't worry, I'm not going to ask that question, yet again...

I am wanting to create my own programming language, just for learning sake.

I don't want anything other than possibly a few links to head me into the right direction.

MSDN Documentation on C# that is specific to what is required to create a language would be great!

For the time being, all I am wanting to create is a very simple language that allows me to Create a Form, add a control to it, give that control a location, and maybe even some properties like a Text property, or maybe even a Color property. That's it!

Any help / advice at all is greatly appreciated!

Thank you :)

Comment: Erm, you want to create a language that is just like C#? What exactly is the point? It's also worth considering that GUI frameworks (like WinForms) have little to nothing to do with languages (like C#). They're implemented separately, the GUI framework is just on top of the language.

Comment: If you want to create a language using .NET objects, then I guess you should: 1. Learn the IL language (which is the bytecode into which each .NET language is compiled to), 2. Write the specs for your language, mapping its features into the .NET architecture, 3. Write the compiler which will generate the IL from a source code written in your language... And of course, I didn't even mention the debugger, etc.. I hope you have a lot of free time on your hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a language or some GUI libraries?

They are a little different, you know?

For a language you could start here:

http://www1.idc.ac.il/tecs/plan.html

(it's a complete course)

or there is this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc136756.aspx

This is for targetting the .net VM, so you don't have to create the VM, and it seems to be very "down to earth"

Answer (score 0):

As for language design, start with something simple. Have a look at Tcl/Tk (http://tcl.tk) for a very simple yet surprisingly powerful language/GUI toolkit design.